# Which kind of inter-application communication should I choose?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, communication, broadcast

I need a push-logic message broadcast function in Android, to push data messages onto other applications that subscribe to the content. The subscribing applications should register with a filter setting and permissions, so that they only receive data they are interested in. This to ensure no unnecessary transmissions are made continuously since that would be a waste of resources.

Is there any ready-to-use mechanism in Android to accomplish this?

I have looked at intent broadcasts, but it seems as if I pack data as a parcelable I don't have a filter function built in. I will always have to send all of the data in one parcelable and then unpack and extract the small part that I am interested in from there(?)

Then I looked at ContentProviders, but it seems they don't push messages onto a recipient, but instead are queried with a sql-like query-string for the content to be fetched. Can a ContentProvider push messages onto a registered recipient using a query as a filter?

Maybe a complicated question to answer, but I give it a shot; Which mechanism should I use, or do I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any ready-to-use mechanism in Android to accomplish this?

That depends on what part of the problem you wish to consider being "ready-to-use". Pushing data to another app is handled via broadcast `Intents`.

> I have looked at intent broadcasts, but it seems as if I pack data as a parcelable I don't have a filter function built in. I will always have to send all of the data in one parcelable and then unpack and extract the small part that I am interested in from there(?)

Your app would do the filtering, then send out broadcasts of the matches. This is a typical approach taken by broker-based "pub/sub" push models: the broker does the filtering, sending out only the relevant messages to subscribers over the communication channel. For example, GCM does not send *every* message destined for *every* device *to* every device and expect devices to do their own filtering -- the GCM servers do the filtering, then send the specific messages to the specific devices.

In some cases, you may be able to leverage `IntentFilter` capabilities to do the filtering for you. For example, suppose a message really represents a file. Files have MIME types. You could include the MIME type of the file in the `Intent` being broadcast, and the receivers could specify the MIME type(s) they are interested in via their filters. Receivers would only get messages from relevant broadcasts.

However, for more arbitrary sorts of subscriptions (e.g., "send me all messages that have certain values in certain JSON-encoded objects"), you would have to implement the filtering yourself.

> Can a ContentProvider push messages onto a registered recipient using a query as a filter?

No, sorry.

Comment: Can I bind to a service to open a datastream to the transmitter from the receiver. Send some filter parameters to the transmitter and then have it write to the stream?

Comment: @user2254314: That is another possibility, but it requires all apps' processes to be in memory all of the time, which is impractical in most situations. If those apps are that closely tied, they should not be separate apps, IMHO.

Comment: "Your app would do the filtering, then send out broadcasts of the matches."

Do I need a different intent for each filterable parameter then?

Comment: @user2254314: No. You would target the "broadcast" of filtered matches to the individual app, probably via `setComponent()` on the `Intent`, so that the "broadcast" only goes to that specific recipient. The subscriber would tell you up front (by some IPC mechanism) what it wants to subscribe to and the `ComponentName` to use. Or, instead of `ComponentName`, it could give you a `PendingIntent`. You would `send()` the `PendingIntent`, supplying extras for the matched message, when a match is encountered.

Comment: Nice. What happens if the subscriber dies? Will the transmitter still continue to broadcast to it then? Do I need to unregister the subscription in onDestroy then?

Comment: @user2254314: Whether you have an "unregister" operation, or use manifest-registered receivers so that you can always deliver the messages, is up to you.

Comment: I have tested using intents, but the result is too slow, so I am opting for the shared-stream approach instead. How can I make the stream accessible to another application. Please note that bytes should be continuously written to the stream, so it should remain open all the time until a subscribing app decides to unsubscribe.

Comment: @user2254314: "How can I make the stream accessible to another application" -- use a `ContentProvider`. "it should remain open all the time until a subscribing app decides to unsubscribe" -- the user has control over their device and can remove any of your background processes from memory at any point in time.

Comment: I suppose I should override the query method of the content provider, but the `Query` method returns a `Cursor`. Can I use the cursor to somehow supply the interrogator with a stream? Or should I create my own method, but in that case, will this method be visible to the interrogator?

Comment: @user2254314: Streams are handled by `openFile()` on the `ContentProvider` side, as streams are pretty much only used for files with providers.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! `openFile()` returns a `ParcelFileDescriptor`. I can see how you would link that to for example a `DatagramSocket` via `static ParcelFileDescriptor  fromDatagramSocket(DatagramSocket datagramSocket)`, but how do I link my simple datastream to the `ParcelFileDescriptor` —that I do not understand.

Comment: I think maybe I got it now. Can I use `Socket`´s  `OutputStream getOutputStream()` to write data to the Socket, and then `static ParcelFileDescriptor fromSocket(Socket socket)` to return the `ParcelFileDescriptor`?

Comment: @user2254314: I have not tried that. I use `ParcelFileDescriptor` and `createPipe()`, personally.

Comment: I would like to send `Parcelable` objects onto an `OutputStream` acquired from `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(ParcelFileDescriptor pfd)`. How can I send a series of `Parcelable` object onto an `OutputStream`? Can I even use `Parcelable` at all? (It seems convenient).

Comment: @user2254314: Use a `Parcel` and the `marshall()` and `unmarshall()` methods, I guess. I have never done this. If you encounter further problems in this area, I would recommend opening a separate SO question, assuming a search turns up nothing of use.

Comment: OK, taken! I know you are not supposed to say thanks here (Don't know why), but thanks! You have been of tremendous help!

Answer (score 1):

1 You can use intents to broadcast keys for filtering in apps then intrested apps can use content provider to fetch full data.
2 Using of different intents for different datasets?

Comment: 1. seems inappropriate since I want data immediately and don't want fetch data, instead have it pushed.

2. Seems to work but seems like an ugly solution. If I have lots of different data sets then I would need to have enormous amounts of different intents(?)